# Какой контейнер использовать для графа с++

Tags: c++, graph, stl-file

Пишу на с++. Есть 3d модель (stl file), которая состоит из треугольников. Мне нужно найти самый короткий путь между двумя вершинами по граням треугольников, как я понимаю, по ребрам графа. Какой контейнер мне лучше использовать для хранения структур вершин? Или может лучше хранить не вершины, а что-то другое ребра, например? Как в общем лучше сформировать входные данные?

[image]

[image: Структура Stl файла бинарного формата]

Comment: Граф можно задать через матрицу смежности, список смежности, матрицу инцидентности или список ребер ([Граф (математика) - Способы представления графа в информатике](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Граф_(математика)#Способы_представления_графа_в_информатике)). Как это программно реализовать - много вариантов.

Comment: @insolor А можете дать пример как можно программно реализовать. В общих чертах хотя бы.

Comment: Вам в любом случае придется хранить вершины, т.к. у каждой вершины есть свои характеристики. Дальше нужно как-то задать связи между вершинами. Лучше всего, насколько я понимаю, будет реализовывать через [список ребер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Список_смежности). Сами вершины лучше хранить отдельно, а в списке смежности использовать указатели на вершины. С реализацией не помогу, т.к. на С++ не пишу.

Comment: А почему бы вам не реализовать свой контейнер и назвать его граф. Т.е. каждый элемент контейнера это вершина и имеет указатели на вершины с которыми связана.

Comment: ИМХО постановка задачи не совсем корректна: надо думать не как хранить граф, а в каком виде подавать его на вход алгоритму... т.к. тут по всей видимости будет использоваться алгоритм Дейкстры, а |V| сопоставимо с |E|, то естественным вариантом будет использовать списки смежности. Дальше вопрос, что делать со значениями весов — в данном случае я бы хранил их вместе со списками — вероятно увеличит локальность алгоритма; хотя можно и каждый раз вычислять и хранить отдельно...